# Is there a way to get a Happy Hour Pokemon without being in Japan?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I enjoy making money in Pokemon X and Y, and I just figured out bout an Inkay event that makes it learn a new move, called Happy Hour (which doubles prize money). Seeing that I live in America (not Japan) is there any way I can obtain a Pokemon with this move?

Comment: Short of trading, doubtful.

Comment: I hope someone breeds a whole bunch with it and wonder trade spams em.

Comment: Even if they do, it wouldn't give the babies the moves. Unless Inlay can learn it by level, egg move, tutor, or tm, you'd have the same as you could catch in the wild.

Comment: If we get lucky, though its probably not gonna happen cause I think the Inlay was Poke center related, it could end up released here. But don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Is there even a Poke-Center in Atlanta?

Comment: As far as I know, they only exist in Japan. At least, I've never heard of an American Poke-Center. But that one I don't know on for sure. I'd say your best bet there would be Google.

Comment: After doing a quick search, [I stand corrected.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Center_(store)#USA) There are indeed American Pokemon Centers. And it is indeed because of Pokemon Centers, specifically the opening of the one in Tokyo Bay. So if someone gets a Pokemon Center opened here extra, maybe we can get it. =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smeargle can Sketch the move down. Find someone who has either the Inkay itself or a Smeargle with Happy Hour, and have them get a Smeargle to Sketch it off them.

Comment: Doesn't help put it on an Inkay though. Event moves don't usually turn into egg moves, and I don't think Smeargle can breed with Inkay anyway

Answer (score 1):

Event Pokémon in X and Y can breed their special moves.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I've certainly never found such, and I've been playing Pokémon for a very long time.

Comment: This is new as of XY, serebii reported on it

Answer (score 1):

You Can't Get The Move HAPPY HOUR because it is only in Japan , And Even if it is a available in the US you have to get it by event or , If Lucky get a Happy Hour Inkay by wonder trade or a Japanese Friend , Passerby Or Acquiantance.